# Could 1 Thessalonians 1:1 "God the Father" imply another Person who is: "God the Son"?

Tags: christology, 1-thessalonians

1 Thessalonians 1:1;

> 1 Paul, and Silvanus, and Timotheus, unto the church of the Thessalonians which is in **God the Father** and in the Lord Jesus Christ: Grace be unto you, and peace, from God our Father, and the Lord Jesus Christ.

And many other verses, like: 2 timothy 1:2; Titus 1:4... etc.

Look: 2 John 1:3.

Could 1 Thessalonians 1:1 "God the Father" imply that there is, also, another Person who is: "**God** the Son"?

The point is, definitely: "God the Father" expression, **Logically**, refers to, implicitly, if not explicitly, refers to the expression "God the Son".

**Logically**, what is the difference between the two expressions:

-**God** the Father.
-**The Father** God?

So, we may consider the expression: "**God** the Son" as Biblical?

Comment: Not according to this text.  That conclusion depends on other materials in the NT.

Comment: The article does not appear in the original verse (εν θεω πατρι  'in God Father' // απο θεου πατρος  'from God Father'). It is arguable (both ways) that the article is necessary for idiomatic reasons in the English language. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @Dottard Not wholly according to this text : agreed. But as one item of evidence among a multitude of evidence, it still deserves its own spotlight of examination (in my view).

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you. Look 2 John 1:3.

Comment: Yes, indeed : θεου πατρος και ...  του υιου του πατρος 'God Father and ... the Son of the Father. Very apposite. [_I in the Father and the Father in me_.  εγω εν τω πατρι και ο πατηρ εν εμοι John 14:11.]

Answer (score 2):

Notice how 1 Thessalonians 1:1 says, "Paul, and Silvanus, and Timotheus, unto the church of the Thessalonians which is in God the Father *and* in the Lord Jesus Christ: Grace be unto you, and peace, from God our Father, *and* the Lord Jesus Christ."

Also, notice how 1 Thessalonians 1:1 doesn't say; "Paul, and Silvanus, and Timotheus, unto the church of the Thessalonians which is in God the Father *who is* the Lord Jesus Christ: Grace be unto you, and peace, from God our Father, *who is* the Lord Jesus Christ."

And it's the exact same situation with 2 Timothy 1:2, Titus 1:4, and 2 John 1:3. The phrases "God the Father" and "Lord Jesus Christ" are never in apposition. The writer used the coordinating conjunction "and" to denote that he is talking about two **separate** elements(i.e. God the Father and the Lord Jesus Christ) in relation to the broader context, as well as in relation to each other.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Excuse me, I mean: imply another person who is God the Son. I will clarify it in new Edit.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't understand. What do you mean, "imply another person who is God the Son." There are only two characters listed in the context; God the Father and Jesus Christ. I don't see any room within the passage for a third person to be "God the Son." Is this what you are trying to get at, though? It'd help if you could clarify. Have a great day! :)

Comment: The verse doesn't imply that the Lord Jesus is God the Son, but it refers to presence of a second person in the Godhead.

Comment: I don't see any way it does. If it does, can you elaborate on the specifics?

Comment: You miunderstood me. You need to Edit your answer.

Comment: Edit it in what manner? Also, can you clarify as to how the given scripture "refers to presence of a second person in the Godhead"?

Comment: Παῦλος καὶ Σιλουανὸς καὶ Τιμόθεος τῇ ἐκκλησίᾳ Θεσσαλονικέων ἐν **θεῷ πατρὶ** καὶ κυρίῳ Ἰησοῦ Χριστῷ χάρις ὑμῖν καὶ εἰρήνη - **the** in "God the Father" is not present in the Greek text. You should first address the significance of why Paul omitted the article to create a text which is literally "God Father."

Answer (score 0):

Christian theology developed logically from the Holy Scripture, and even if the expression "God-Son" is absent there, it is throughly implied, as to leave no room for not claiming the theological truthfulness of the expression God-Son. Why? Because the Son's divinity is clearly affirmed in Gospels and He is called God in the very first sentence of the Fourth Gospel, and Paul equates Him, the Son, Lord Jesus Christ, with "God" of the Psalms 45:6 in Hebrews 1:8.

Thus, if Father is God and the Son is God, then as there is legitimacy in expression God-the-Father, absolutely the same legitimacy follows for the term  God-the-Son, exactly which was adopted by the Christian theology out of theological necessity.

Analogy: the sun is the enlightener and is called in an astronomical book "How the sun works" by Dghrkty Brsjwhson,  "sun-the-enlightener"; now, in the ch. 7 of the same book of Dghrkty Brsjwhson is stated that sun's ray is enlightener, yet, he does not coin the term "ray-the-enlightener" in his book. However, his post-doc student Fghtwdsqway Prtewsty in her book "Suntan on a beach", already coins a term "ray-the-enlightener", and her supervisor, the mentioned Dr.Dgrkty Brsjwhson reads and approves it, moreover, does not even approve it, for even the question of approval does not rise in him so natural it is.

Comment: There is a problem, however, with the term, "God the Son," in relation to "God the Father." It makes it sound as though the Father and the Son are the same God, but they aren't. They make up one God, the LORD God. Each of them can be rightfully called, "God," but not the same God. The Father is 1/2 of God, and the Son is 1/2 of God.

Comment: @Rajesh Christians have a relationship with the Father, Son, and the Holy Spirit who are the one God. The Godhead consists of three distinct Persons and that is how God chose to manifest Himself in the Bible. If your in a relationship with the Father/Son/Holy Spirit, then you must be in a relationship with them all, for there is only one God. If you deny one, you deny all. Also, God is indivisible and cannot be divided or separated. There is no 1/2 God or 1/3 God. What makes God one is their shared nature manifested at three distinct persons. Levan Gigineishvilli has it right.

Comment: That's logically impossible. I don't subscribe to the notion of God being able to accomplish the logically impossible. If A = C, and B = C, A = B. This is the most basic of logic. If Father = God, and Son = God, and Holy Spirit = God, then Father = Son = Holy Spirit. The Trinity doctrine rejects this conclusion while asserting the very proposition that inevitably leads to this conclusion, ergo in order for the Trinity doctrine to be correct God would need to ability to accomplish the logically impossible. And I don't believe He can. But it's not my business if anyone else does. Take care. :)

Comment: @Rajesh So you believe the doctrine of the Trinity cannot be proved to you either deductively or via any other method or rational proof. I offer the following syllogism, deduce this: If the Bible teaches that there is only one God, and If in the Bible the Father is identified as God, and If in the Bible His Son is identified as God, and If in the Bible their Spirit is identified as God, then the doctrine of the Trinity is valid, or the Bible is wrong. So how does the Bible identify God? By His names, His titles, His unique attributes, His unique actions, His worship. Prove me wrong?

Comment: "If the Bible teaches that there is only one God, and If in the Bible the Father is identified as God, and If in the Bible His Son is identified as God, and If in the Bible their Spirit is identified as God, then the doctrine of the Trinity is valid, or the Bible is wrong." The Holy Spirit is never called God. The Holy Spirit is an extension of God(the Father + His Word, Jesus), His personal presence, and the means by which He accomplishes all He wills. Anything that can be attributed to the Holy Spirit, can be attributed to God. But nothing can be attributed solely to the Holy Spirit.

Comment: Wrong!  Acts 5:3-4, note vs4, "While it remained unsold, did it not remain your own? And after it was sold, was it not under your control? Why is it that you have conceived this deed in your heart? You have not lied to men BUT TO GOD." If the Holy Spirit is not a distinct person from the Father and the Son why does   Peter not say, You have lied to God? Or why at John 14:16, And I will ask the Father, and He will give you ANOTHER Helper, that He may be with you forever." Yes, the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son, that's not the issue. Why is He identified as a distinct Person?

Comment: @Rajesh—“The Father is 1/2 of God, and the Son is 1/2 of God.” Absolutely. Not.

Comment: @Mr. Bond "If the Holy Spirit is not a distinct person from the Father and the Son why does Peter not say, You have lied to God?" He does say that. Acts 5:3-4 "Then Peter said, “Ananias, why have you let Satan fill your heart? You lied to the Holy Spirit, and you kept some of the money for yourself. 4 The property was yours to sell or not sell, as you wished. And after selling it, the money was also yours to give away. How could you do a thing like this? You weren’t lying to us but to God!" By lying to the Holy Spirit, Ananias lied to God, because the Spirit is the personal presence of God.

Comment: @Rajesh God is Trinity and 1/2  talk about God is against Christian theology. God naturally gives birth to His Son (and, similarly, gives procession to the Holy Spirit). This "naturally" means that Father cannot not give birth to His Son, thus being the Son's eternal Father. Giving birth, the Father also gives the entirety of His essence to the Son, and since the Son possesses entirety of the Father's essence, He is also 100% God. The essence of the Father and the Son is identical, but Father is eternal Source and the Son is eternally Sourced. Thus, they differ in Persons, being Both one God.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, "Anything that can be attributed to the Holy Spirit, can be attributed to God." God, Yahweh, made up of Jesus and the Father, sent His Holy Spirit  to see the hearts of men, and to reveal them to Peter. Notice what it says in Acts 5:9 "And Peter said, “How could the two of you even think of conspiring to test the Spirit of the Lord like this?..." They were conspiring to test the Spirit? Ananias and his wife didn't talk to the Holy Spirit, or say they would do anything to the Spirit. So how could they possibly test the Spirit? By testing the One who sent it.

Comment: @Levan Gigineishvili "The essence of the Father and the Son is identical, but Father is eternal Source and the Son is eternally Sourced." I agree 100%. They are eternal spirit beings. The Father is the source of the Son, and the Son/Word is the source of everything in creation(whether physical or spiritual), thus one can say Yahweh God created ALL things; creation can be attributed to both the Father and the Son, because it is through them all things came to be. THEY are Yahweh God. Not the Holy Spirit. The Spirit is called GOD'S Spirit for a reason; it belongs to Yahweh, not it IS Yahweh.

Comment: @Rajesh Your mixed up. I told you that the Holy Spirit IS a distinct person from the Father and Son. The one being of God chose to manifest Himself as 3 distinct persons. Not three separate persons as some say, distinct. I also told you that the HS proceeds from the Father and the Son. At Genesis 1:2 it says, "and the Spirit of God was moving over the surface of the waters. The other verses at Genesis 1 mostly states, "And God said/saw." Notice at vs 2 the HS is in distinction from God. Now, the problem I have with you  is regarding this 1/2 God business? Where did you come up with that?

Comment: @Rajesh Are you communicating only your own convictions and ideas, or do you follow a certain religious confession? Which one? I myself am a Christian of Orthodox confession and my ideas are in agreement with the theological positions of the church fathers of the 7 ecumenical councils. And you?

Comment: I don't follow any religious confessions. And, as for that appeal to authority, I don't let any imperfect men(including me) dictate the meaning of scripture for me. I let God guide me through His Holy Spirit as He sees fit. I don't think I have all the answers, and I don't think I ever will, because that's not the purpose of the Holy Spirit(to help you learn all the answers to everything). But certainly I won't figure out all the answers by letting men dictate the meaning of scriptures for me either. So if I'm going to choose one or the other, I'll go with the Holy Spirit and stop there.